# When the player is fall the collision game object doesn't destroyed immediately

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I have a problem. I created a game with coins that the player collects. I a code that when the player collisions with the coin the coin will be destroyed.  When he on the same Y all the game is good. However, when the player fall on a coin he get stuck on the coin for a second and after the coin is destroyd. and it is not happen immediately.
I want that when the player collisions the coin from fall it will be destroyed immediately.

This is the code:

```
if(collision.collider.tag.Equals("coin"))
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trigger instead. That way you would not impact the coin and trade physics.

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(collider2D collision){}
```